# What does the make() method do in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, methods

In the Laravel documentation, I found the following - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#the-make-method

but I am still confused as to what exactly the make() method does. I know the create() method uses the make() method and then persists them into the database, so does make() methods just temporarily save it in php tinker or something? Sorry, I'm Laravel noob. I'm trying to figure out these functions. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `make` method will return an instance of the class or interface you request.
Where you request to make an interface, Laravel will lookup a binding for that interface to a concrete class.

E.g.

```
$app->make('App\Services\MyService'); // new \App\Services\MyService.
```

One advantage to using the `make` method, is that Laravel will automatically inject any dependencies the class may define in it's constructor.

E.g. an instance of the `Mailer` class would be automatically injected here.

```
namespace App\Services;

use \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;

class MyService
{
    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer) {
        $this->mailer = new Mailer;
    }
}
```

Comment: would there be a documentation I may have missed when searching for the make() method on Laravel.com? Thank you :)

Comment: Nothing more than the page you've already linked to. Read the whole page to better understand the IoC container, as it's all related. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container

Answer (score 0):

I discovered recently that when you use make (), you are installing the class and you can access the methods of that class or model, this is a useful for the Test and validate that you are getting what you want Example:
User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function getRouteKeyName ()
     {
         return 'name';
     }
}
```

Test user

```
class UserTest extends TestCase
{
  public function route_key_name_is_set_to_name ()
     {
       $ user = factory (User :: class) -> make ();
       $ this-> assertEquals ('name', $ user-> getRouteKeyName ());
       // When you access the getRouteKeyName method you get the return, that is 'name'
     }
}
```

On the other hand if you use "create" that would give an error because you are creating a user